# Left join with a while loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

MY CODE:

```
// variables
      $user_id = $_SESSION['user_ID']; // session ID

      // query db for user info
      $get_info = $conn->prepare("SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name,
        users.last_name,
        users.country_origin,
        users.looking_for,
        users.exp_yrs,
        users_skills.user_id,
        users_skills.user_skill
        FROM `users`
        LEFT JOIN `users_skills`
        ON users.user_id = ?
        AND users_skills.user_id = users.user_id
        $get_info->bind_param('s',$user_id);
        $get_info->execute();
        $row_user_details = $get_info->get_result()->fetch_Assoc(); // get result 

 <div class="col"><label class="input-filled"><input name="first_name" required value="<?php echo $row_user_details['first_name']; ?>">

 <div class="col"><label class="input-filled"><input name="last_name" required value="<?php echo $row_user_details['last_name']; ?>">


While(" i can't use $row_user_details = $get_info->fetch_Assoc()"){
 <div class="col"><label class="input-filled"><input name="last_name" required value="<?php echo $row_user_details['user_skill']; ?>">
}
```

i am not sure what to put in the while () cuz i need to use the values of the query outside of the while loop aswell as you can see from the code, i have been at it for 1-2 hrs and just can't figure it out

user_skill is multiple data in one table that has the same user_id
where as first name and last name is only one value from the user row

DB layout:

```
users_skills TABLE:
ID | user_id | user_skill |
1  | 1       | something1 |
2  | 1       | something2 |
3  | 1       | something3 |
4  | 2       | somethine4 |
5  | 6       | somethine5 |
```

```
users TABLE:
user_id | first_name | last_name | some more stuff |
1       | john       | key       | secrets         |
```

the session ID is = user_id // in this case 1

*This code has been shorten so not to reveal info to the public but it works the same*

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to concatenate the `user_skill` column, so the <div> would contain user_skill_1, user_skill_2, etc.?

Comment: If you need to use it in a loop and outside, maybe you could [fetch it all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all) and then use that result as you please?

Comment: @Mark yes like a loop

Comment: as you can see from the db table i want it to show all the skills related to the user id

Comment: @MARKO, okay, so you could do the `while($row_user_details = $get_info->fetch_Assoc())` and concat all the fields into one variable like `$somevar .= ' '.$row_user_details['user_skill']`, and then show the <div>.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you code is ok, just on ` ON users.user_id = ?` should be ' WHERE users.user_id = ?' as last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

So, if you already have

```
<div class="col"><label class="input-filled"><input name="first_name" required value="<?php echo $row_user_details['first_name']; ?>">
<div class="col"><label class="input-filled"><input name="last_name" required value="<?php echo $row_user_details['last_name']; ?>">
```

And the problem is this line

```
While(" i can't use $row_user_details = $get_info->fetch_Assoc()"){
 <div class="col"><label class="input-filled"><input name="last_name" required value="<?php echo $row_user_details['user_skill']; ?>">
}
```

You could rewrite that to

```
$user_skill = '';
while($row_user_details = $get_info->fetch_Assoc()) {
    $user_skill .= ' '.$row_user_details['user_skill'];
}

<div class="col">
    <label class="input-filled"><input name="last_name" required value="<?php echo $user_skill; ?>">
</div>
```

Also, you would have to add WHERE clause to you SQL query to get only particular user_id.

This way you will get $userskill in one column.
I hope I understood what you wanted to do.

Comment: HI Mark i appreciate you help i did figure it out myself but your code did help me see my problem so i will mark it as the answer

Comment: @MARKO, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query gives this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418d0b/1

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.FirstName,
        users.LastName,
        users.Address,
        users.City,
        users_skills.user_id,
        users_skills.skill
        FROM `users`
        LEFT JOIN `users_skills`
        ON users.user_id = 1
        AND users_skills.user_id = users.user_id
```

```
user_id FirstName   LastName    Address City    user_id skill
1   Tom B   Erichsen    4006 Stavanger  Stavanger   1   Erichsen
1   Tom B   Erichsen    4006 Stavanger  Stavanger   1   Tom B
1   Tom B   Erichsen    4006 Stavanger  Stavanger   1   4006 Stavanger
2   Tom B   John    4006 Stavanger  Stavanger   (null)  (null)
3   Tom B   Tes 4006 Stavanger  Stavanger   (null)  (null)
4   Tom B   Smith   4006 Stavanger  Stavanger   (null)  (null)
5   Tom B   Jane    4006 Stavanger  Stavanger   (null)  (null)
```

Can you tell me what do you want to achieve? I assume you want for each user to get his skills? Or just for Session User?

To get ALL skills for all users

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.FirstName,
        users.LastName,
        users.Address,
        users.City,
        users_skills.user_id,
        users_skills.skill
        FROM `users`
        LEFT JOIN `users_skills`
        ON   users_skills.user_id = users.user_id
```

To get ALL skills for user 1

```
        users.LastName,
        users.Address,
        users.City,
        users_skills.user_id,
        users_skills.skill
        FROM `users`
        LEFT JOIN `users_skills`
        ON users_skills.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE users.user_id = 1
```

**Just an idea:**

I would go different
Create a function that get skills

```
function getUserSkills($userId){
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM users_skills ";
    $query .= "WHERE user_id=" . $userId . " ";      
    $skillset = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  

    $results = array();
    while ($skill = mysqli_fetch_assoc($skillset)){
        $results[] = $skill;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Then just call it when You need user skills

```
$userid = sql_prep($_SESSION['userid']);
$skills = getUserSkills($userid);

foreach ($skill as $skills) {
    echo $skill['skill_name']. '<br>';
}
```

Probably same for getUser($user_id)

Comment: i want to get all the skills for the session user

Comment: cuz the user has more than one skill

Comment: `WHERE users.user_id = 1 ` replace 1 with ? so you can pass Session User id

Comment: thanks for your help but i figured out a better way :)

Comment: I updated with different approach, check it if it hepls.